# Regex.Replace to deidentify/normalize columnar text

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace, multiple-columns, pad

VB2010: I am using RegEx to de-identify a block of text and also normalize the text. That is to say to take lines of text and de-identify the name and the confirmation code and then normalize the text so that data lines up in columns. I have almost all of it except the last part where the  confirmation code is preceded by a variable number of dots and a package id that is 2 to 4 characters long or could be missing.

```
    'regex
    Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("(?<pre>^\s{0,2}(\d{1,3})\s(\d\d))(.+?)(?<post>\.\.(\d{1,3})\." + "(\w)\s((\w+?|\.\.)))(?<dots>\.+)(\w{6})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)

    'this is the replacement string
    Dim replacement As String = "${pre}******/*****${post}${dots}******"

    'replace the matched text in the InputText using the replacement pattern
    Dim result As String = MyRegex.Replace(Input, replacement)
```

My test input with a number, name, number, misc code, package id, and confirmation code on each line:

```
  1 01SMITH/CH..1.A E2T......AAABBB
  2 01MTC..1.A ..............CCCDDD
  3 01GRIFFIN/JOHN..1.A E2...EEEFFF
  4 01EL/MARY..1.Z E2XT......GGGHHH
  5 02BUBBA/BILLY..2.A E2....IIIJJJ
  6 01HILL/THOR..1.A E2WW....KKKLLL
```

My output so far:

```
  1 01******/*****..1.A E2T......******
  2 01******/*****..1.A ..............******
  3 01******/*****..1.A E2...******
  4 01******/*****..1.Z E2XT......******
  5 02******/*****..2.A E2....******
  6 01******/*****..1.A E2WW....******
```

I am de-identifying the name and the confirmation code but the code package id before the confirmation code is variable so that is throwing off my columnar output. Kind of stuck on the end part of it but am really close. I am aiming to do it one one regex but it may not be possible. Is it possible to pad a regex replacement?

Update with a solution:

```
    'regex (added one more group for the package id so I can determine its length)
    Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("(?<pre>^\s{0,2}(\d{1,3})\s(\d\d))(.+?)(?<post>\.\.(\d{1,3})\.(\w)\s(?<pkid>(\w+?|\.\.)))(?<dots>\.+)(\w{6})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)

    'use the MatchEvaluator to examine each match and adjust accordingly
    deid = MyRegex.Replace(deid, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
                                                        Return m.Groups("pre").Value &
                                                            "******/*****" &
                                                            m.Groups("post").Value &
                                                            New String("."c, 5 - m.Groups("pkid").Value.Length) &
                                                            "******"
                                                    End Function))
```

I run that through the test data and here is what I get:

```
-----Input------------------------------------------------
1 01SMITH/CH..1.A E2T......AAABBB
2 01MTC..1.A ..............CCCDDD
3 01GRIFFIN/JOHN..1.A E2...EEEFFF
4 01EL/MARY..1.Z E2XT......GGGHHH
5 02BUBBA/BILLY..2.A E2....IIIJJJ
6 01HILL/THOR..1.A E2WW....KKKLLL
-----Output-----------------------------------------------
1 01******/*****..1.A E2T..******
2 01******/*****..1.A .....******
3 01******/*****..1.A E2...******
4 01******/*****..1.Z E2XT.******
5 02******/*****..2.A E2...******
6 01******/*****..1.A E2WW.******
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the output you want to obtain?

Comment: I take it that you know it's easy to do without a regex?

Comment: stribizhev the output as shown but lined up. Right now everything lines up except the confirmation code. Andrew I do know I can do that without regex however the data above is part of a bigger document and I'm hoping to just replace this part.

Comment: What if you just had output lines similar to `1 01********..1.A E2T......******`, without the slash in the first asterisk group?

Comment: Yes but the package id can be 2 to 4 chars and the number of dots after it can vary too. I want to say that if regex had a padding specifier I could take the package id and pad it up to 4 chars then that would work. In fact .NET RegEx does have an overload for predicates but only for single/simple replacements.

Comment: Please check my solution. I know it does not look nice when a slash is not exactly in the middle of the asterisk group, but I do not think it is possible to work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, there can be a better way, but it is possible to achieve what you want with [your regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cpre%3E%5Cs%7B0%2C2%7D(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%5Cs(%5Cd%5Cd))(.%2B%3F)(%3F%3Cpost%3E%5C.%5C.(%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D)%5C.(%5Cw)%5Cs((%5Cw%2B%3F%7C%5C.%5C.)))(%3F%3Cdots%3E%5C.%2B)(%5Cw%7B6%7D)&i=1%2001SMITH%2FCH..1.A%20E2T......AAABBB%0D%0A2%2001MTC..1.A%20..............CCCDDD%0D%0A3%2001GRIFFIN%2FJOHN..1.A%20E2...EEEFFF%0D%0A4%2001EL%2FMARY..1.Z%20E2XT......GGGHHH%0D%0A5%2002BUBBA%2FBILLY..2.A%20E2....IIIJJJ%0D%0A6%2001HILL%2FTHOR..1.A%20E2WW....KKKLLL&o=im) and [`Regex.Replace` using a `MatchEvaluator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **`evaluator`**
>   *Type: System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator*
>   A custom method that examines each match and returns either the original matched string or a replacement string.

The point is to get the length of Group 3 and Group 8, and repeat the `*` the same number of times. To add a forward slash, we can find the middle by dividing the length of Group 3 in 2. `StrDup` is a handy function that "multiplies" the string the specified number of times.

Here is a VB.NET code:

```
Dim Input As String = "1 01SMITH/CH..1.A E2T......AAABBB" & Environment.NewLine & "2 01MTC..1.A ..............CCCDDD" & Environment.NewLine & "3 01GRIFFIN/JOHN..1.A E2...EEEFFF" & Environment.NewLine & "4 01EL/MARY..1.Z E2XT......GGGHHH" & Environment.NewLine & "5 02BUBBA/BILLY..2.A E2....IIIJJJ" & Environment.NewLine & "6 01HILL/THOR..1.A E2WW....KKKLLL"
Dim MyRegex As Regex = New Regex("(?<pre>^\s{0,2}(\d{1,3})\s(\d\d))(.+?)(?<post>\.\.(\d{1,3})\." + "(\w)\s((\w+?|\.\.)))(?<dots>\.+)(\w{6})", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim result As String = MyRegex.Replace(Input, New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match)
                                    Return m.Groups("pre").Value &
                                    StrDup(m.Groups(3).Value.Length, "*").Insert(m.Groups(3).Value.Length / 2, "/") &
                                    m.Groups("post").Value &
                                    m.Groups("dots").Value &
                                    StrDup(m.Groups(8).Value.Length, "*")
                              End Function))
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Result:

```
1 01****/****..1.A E2T......******
2 01**/*..1.A ..............******
3 01******/******..1.A E2...******
4 01****/***..1.Z E2XT......******
5 02******/*****..2.A E2....******
6 01****/*****..1.A E2WW....******
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure the intention is to replace any name with the fixed string "******/*****" rather than replacing the characters with asterisks.

Comment: Andrew yes that was my original intention but with this bit of help I think this is going to work. let me test the code with some modifications and will append to the original request.

Comment: stribizhev thanks for the tip. I don't think I have ever used the MatchEvaluator but will definitely add it to my toolbox. Basing the final solution on your suggestion I tweaked it a bit to adjust the dots in between the package id and confirmation code. This was the variable that needed to be modified and it works. Don't even need the "dots" group. Final code in the op.